# SQL - Get answer from query as a single number

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

The following code returns a couple of numbers, identifying people who take part in more than three activities.

```
SELECT pnr
FROM Participates
GROUP BY pnr
HAVING count(activities)>3;
```

I want the answer to be the number of people who participate in more than three activities though, i.e. "4", instead of four unique numbers. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access supports derived tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfParticipants FROM 
(
SELECT pnr
  FROM Participates
 GROUP BY pnr
HAVING count(activities)>3
) T
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need a WHERE clause on the `pnr` field to uniquely identify one of your groupings:

```
SELECT COUNT(pnr)
FROM Participates
GROUP BY pnr
WHERE pnr = 'whatever'
HAVING COUNT(activities)>3
```

The order of my clauses might be wrong

Answer (score -1):

```
Select Count(Distinct pnr)
From Participates
Having Count(activities) > 3
```

Comment: There is no 'GROUP BY' here so the `Count(Distinct pnr)` would count the distinct pnr in the whole table and would return that as the result if the number of activities in the whole table happened to be more than 3.